# Send HTTP Post with Python

Tags: python, http, post

I want to make a program where I can send HTTP post requests and respond.

So, I want to send THIS post:

```
POST https: //example.com/index.php?s=&&app=box&module=ajax&section=coreAjax&secure_key=&type=submit&lastid=87311&global=1 HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 10
Accept: text/javascript, text/html, application/xml, text/xml, */*
X-Prototype-Version: 1.7.2
Origin: https://example.com
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Referer: https://x.com/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: cookieconsent_status=dismiss;
```

And then enter the request body:

```
message=                    # Which I will make: "message= %s" % (messagex))
```

But I do not know how to send them and can´t seem to find any way online, could someone help please?

Comment: have you had a look at http://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/ ? Or the httplib library ?

Comment: @ValLeNain Yeah, but I´m really new to python and don´t really know much on how to do this :/

Comment: Read the paragraphs Custom headers and More complicated POST requests (http://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers) that's exactly what you need and is very simple. Remember that you have to try something before posting on StackOverflow ;)

Comment: @ValLeNain Sorry, I´m looking at it but still don´t really know how to do it, could you please help me? I´d really appreciate it :D Sorry for beeing a total retard :(

Answer (score 0):

The main parts are:

```
import requests # you have to install this library, with pip for example

# define your custom headers (as many as you want)

headers = {
  'X-Prototype-Version': '1.7.2'
}

# define your URL params (!= of the body of the POST request)

params = {
  'your_first_param': 'its_value',
  'your_second_param': 'its_value'
}

# define the body of the POST request

data = {
  'message' : 'your message'
}

# send the POST request

response = requests.post('https://example.com/index.php', params=params, data=data, headers=headers)

# here is the response

print response.text
```

Hope that helps.